# What is the ratio of curing salt versus table salt in a recipe?

Tags: substitutions

My soppressatta recipe calls for 2.50 lbs. of table salt for every 100 lbs. of meat. How much curing salt would I use in place of table salt?

Comment: I would recommend using a recipe from a reputable source (which has taken food safety guidelines into account) that already includes the curing salt.  Curing salt will alter flavor as well as providing protection from botulism, etc., so it's probably better to use a recipe that has already taken any flavor from the curing agents into account in any spice mixtures, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Athanasius, it's best to follow a reputable recipe and not mess with substitutions when curing meats. You're playing with fire. The very fact that you would ask in that way tells me you don't have the background to even be thinking about it, since there is more than one type of curing salt.

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curing_salt)

> Curing salts are used in food preservation to prevent or slow spoilage by bacteria or fungus. Generally they are used for pickling meats as part of the process to make sausage or cured meat. Curing salts are generally a mixture of table salt and sodium nitrate. Common types of curing salts are Prague powder #1, which is 6% sodium nitrite and 94% table salt, and Prague powder #2 which also includes sodium nitrate

It doesn't get much more reputable than Michael Ruhlman, and he's written a Bible on the subject of Charcuterie: [Charcuterie: The Craft of Salting, Smoking, and Curing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393240053). Wow, it's even available for the Kindle, I might have to get that.

On-line, he goes specifically into [soppressata](http://ruhlman.com/2011/10/soppressata-recipe/).